# git pull fatal error

Tags: git, virtualbox, git-pull, ubuntu-12.04

When I try to trigger **git pull** command it is returning an error as follows:

> mert@eren-VirtualBox:~/restoranya/restoranya$ git pull origin master
>
> error: object file
>   .git/objects/2a/0836034919f0cfe0f8f1ab98037884dd1c93de is empty
>
> fatal: loose object 2a0836034919f0cfe0f8f1ab98037884dd1c93de (stored
>   in
>   .git/objects/2a/0836034919f0cfe0f8f1ab98037884dd1c93de) is corrupt
>
> mert@eren-VirtualBox:~/restoranya/restoranya$ fatal: The remote end
>   hung up unexpectedly

Whats the reason for such an error? What should I do to recover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, that object is corrupt in your origin remote.

You need another clone of this repository where you can run

```
git cat-file -t 2a0836034919f0cfe0f8f1ab98037884dd1c93de
```

with no error, and you want to inject a good version of that object into origin’s object database.

Describing the fix can be a tricky because we are talking about multiple clones that may reside on different hosts and possibly owned by different users. The steps below assume that you have shell access to the host of your origin as the user that owns your origin repository. The prompt `origin$` below indicates commands to be run on the machine that hosts your origin.

The bad object on origin is in loose format, so the final step of the restore is a simple copy.

Assuming the object in the good clone is also loose, then run

```
origin$ cp /path/to/good-repo/.git/objects/\
2a/0836034919f0cfe0f8f1ab98037884dd1c93de \
/path/to/origin/objects/2a
```

if your origin is a bare repository or

```
origin$ cp /path/to/good-repo/.git/objects/\
2a/0836034919f0cfe0f8f1ab98037884dd1c93de \
/path/to/origin/.git/objects/2a
```

otherwise.

If in the good clone this object is stored in a pack, then you have to get it out. I recommend doing this in a scratch throw-away clone.

```
origin$ git clone file:///path/to/good-repo /tmp/restore-repo
```

If `good-repo` is on another machine, the clone URL will be different.

```
origin$ git clone user@other-machine:src/foo/.git /tmp/restore-repo
```

Change to the directory that holds your temporary repository.

```
origin$ cd /tmp/restore-repo
```

Move the pack files out of the object database because git won’t unpack the objects if it thinks it already has them.

```
origin$ mkdir /tmp/restore-packs
origin$ mv .git/objects/pack/* /tmp/restore-packs
```

Now you’re ready to unpack.

```
origin$ for pack in /tmp/restore-packs/*.pack; do
  git unpack-objects -r < $pack
done
```

The `-r` option tells `git-unpack-objects` to continue unpacking even if it encounters a bad object.

At this point, `/tmp/restore-repo` should now contain 2a08360… as a loose object, so run

```
origin$ cp /tmp/restore-repo/.git/objects\
2a/0836034919f0cfe0f8f1ab98037884dd1c93de \
/path/to/origin/objects/2a
```

or

```
origin$ cp /tmp/restore-repo/.git/objects\
2a/0836034919f0cfe0f8f1ab98037884dd1c93de \
/path/to/origin/.git/objects/2a
```

depending on whether origin is a bare repository.