# Object file .git/objects/ is empty from git pull

Tags: git, git-pull

I created a Git repository on computer A, and cloned this to computer B. Then I updated A and committed and pushed to remote, everything is working.

But when I run these commands in computer B:

```
git status -s
```

or

```
git pull
```

I get the error:

> error: object file .git/objects/eb/c57584a88e2bfffab31fe651368c0f74e8e399 is empty
>   fatal: loose object ebc57584a88e2bfffab31fe651368c0f74e8e399 (stored in .git/objects/eb/c57584a88e2bfffab31fe651368c0f74e8e399) is corrupt

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please look at here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706215/how-to-fix-git-error-object-file-is-empty

Comment: I just want to know how this error occur.I don't want to follow these so many steps to solve the error,I want to find the reason and avoid it next time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111728/how-do-i-deal-with-corrupted-git-object-files I don't know more about this

Comment: possible duplicate of [git pull fatal error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030181/git-pull-fatal-error)